# primefaces scheduler in bootsfaces tabview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bootsfaces

Hi friends of programming,

I have a problem showing a primefaces schedule inside a bootsfaces tabview.
The scheduler is not rendered and I do not know why.

I know that I have to activate lazyloading in the primefaces tabview, but it will be added in Bootsfaces 1.0.0.

Is there a workaround for my problem?

It is technically no problem for me to use the primefaces tabview, but the I have the same problem with the courseViewOptions, which is noch rendered.

CourseView.xhtml:

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h3>
    <h:outputText value="#{courseView.currentCourse.name}" />
</h3>

<b:tabView activeIndex="0"  ajax="false">
    <b:tab title="#{lang.course_overview}">
        <ui:include src="coursesViewOverview.xhtml" />
    </b:tab>
    <b:tab title="#{lang.course_grades}">
        <ui:include src="coursesViewGrades.xhtml" />
    </b:tab>
    <b:tab title="#{lang.course_calendar}">
        <ui:include src="coursesViewCalendar.xhtml" />
    </b:tab>
    <b:tab title="#{lang.course_tutorials}">
        <ui:include src="coursesViewTutorials.xhtml" />
    </b:tab>

    <b:tab title="#{lang.course_config}">
        <f:facet name="anchor">
            <b:iconAwesome name="cog" spin="true" />
        </f:facet>
        <ui:include src="coursesViewOptions.xhtml" />
    </b:tab>
</b:tabView>
</ui:fragment>
```

CourseViewCalendar.xhtml

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <b:panelGrid colSpans="12" columnClasses="value">
        <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{calendarView.eventModel}"
            widgetVar="myschedule" timeZone="GMT+2">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{calendarView.onDateSelect}"
                update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{calendarView.onEventSelect}"
                update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{calendarView.onEventMove}"
                update="messages" />
            <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{calendarView.onEventResize}"
                update="messages" />

        </p:schedule>
    </b:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="#{lang.event_details}"
        showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="eventTitle" value="#{lang.event_name}" />
            <p:inputText id="eventTitle" value="#{calendarView.event.title}"
                required="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="eventDescription"
                value="#{lang.event_description}" />
            <p:inputTextarea id="eventDescription"
                value="#{calendarView.event.description}" required="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="eventFrom" value="#{lang.event_from}" />
            <p:calendar id="eventFrom" value="#{calendarView.event.startDate}"
                timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />

            <p:outputLabel for="eventTo" value="#{lang.event_to}" />
            <p:calendar id="eventTo" value="#{calendarView.event.endDate}"
                timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />

            <p:outputLabel for="eventAllDay" value="#{lang.event_all_day}" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="eventAllDay"
                value="#{calendarView.event.allDay}" />

            <p:outputLabel for="searchPeople" value="#{lang.event_searchPeople}" />
            <ui:include src="/secured/fragment_search.xhtml" />

            <p:commandButton type="resetEventButton" value="#{lang.event_reset}" />
            <p:commandButton id="addEventButton" value="#{lang.event_save}"
                actionListener="#{calendarView.addEvent}"
                oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
</ui:fragment>
```

CourseViewOptions.xhtml

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <ui:include src="changePermission.xhtml" />

    <b:listLinks>
        <b:navLink href="#changePermission" value="Todo Rechte ändern"
            iconAlign="left" iconAwesome="plus-circle" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#changePermission"
            onclick="$('#changePermission').modal();return false;" />
    </b:listLinks>


</ui:fragment>
```

Thank you for your help and happy coding.
Marcel

EDIT: Firebug shows me the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 value">
        <div id="j_idt71:schedule">
            <div id="j_idt71:schedule_container"></div>
            <input id="j_idt71:schedule_view" type="hidden" value="month" autocomplete="off" name="j_idt71:schedule_view">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The schedule_container is empty. I dont know why.

Comment: Check what your browser developer tool shows you html wise. Most likely an initial 0 height and width of the container.

Comment: I cannot find height and width = 0 in any of the container of the schedule. Or may I add them?

Comment: Actually, I don't see the prime:schedule component in your code snippets. By the look of it, you've pasted the same code twice. I suppose the second listing should contain the calendar widget.

Comment: @Kukeltje I checked the source code of Marcel's post. It shows the same b:tabView section in the listings of CourseView.xhtml and of CourseViewCalendar.xhtml.

Comment: @StevenRaugh: a now I see what you mean, sorry

Comment: The JavaScript source code of p:calendar is some 10000 lines of JavaScript long, so it's hard to trace down the error. But my first impression is that it calculates the available height and width. So chances are p:schedule is initialized before the b:tabs become visible. As long as the tabs are invisible, the available space is 0px by 0px. Maybe it helps to set the size of the tabs using the contentStyle attribute (but as I said, that's just a guess).

Comment: Also see https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/2601. You might also try to call PF('widgetvar').update() (bind that to a button during the experimental phase, and to an "onclick" handler of b:tab later). (Maybe we'll have to an "onclicked" handle because "onclicked" is executed before showing the tab. If so, please open an issue on our bug tracker).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot get it running for me.
I added contentStyle and I tried to add this:
<p:commandButton id="testscheduleButton1" value="oncomplete"
   oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();" />
  <p:commandButton id="testscheduleButton2" value="onclick"
   onclick="PF('myschedule').update();" />